# Matching the time complexity to each of the two algorithms

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, big-o

I just wanted to double-check if my answer is correct, as I'm a complete beginner. I'm trying to answer the following question:

"Algorithm A blurs a 1 000 000 pixel image in 1 second; Algorithm B blurs the same image in 0.7 seconds. One algorithm has a time complexity of O(n) and the other O(n^2). Is it possible to determine which algorithm has which complexity?"

Am I correct in thinking that the one with the linear complexity would be faster, considering they both operate on the same data set? If not, what additional information would I need?

Thank you in advance for your time and help.

Comment: Time complexity does not say anything about the runtime. It says something about how runtime *increases*. So you can not say that algorithm A is per se the linear one and vice-versa.

Comment: Ahh, good point. Thank you for clarifying this :)

Comment: No. big-O notation informs you about how an algorythm *scales* with input size, not how fast it is. For example, sleep sort has complexity O(n log n) but takes "forever". You need at least 2 samples to determine which belongs to which ( given you know these are the 2 possibilities ).

Comment: Did you look up the definition of big O and see how to apply it in this case? If not, why not? If you did, where did you get stuck applying it here?

Comment: Is your question answered by the comments or do you need further explanations?

Comment: @akuzminykh Yes, it is. Thank you :]